# Comparing if two types are "literally" the same

Tags: c++

Let's say we have two types

```
using t1 = int*; using t2 = int*;
```

I know that `std::is_same<t1, t2>::value` will give us `true`. And what is, or, is there a template tool to achieve the following?

```
tool<t1, t2>::value == false;
tool<t1, t1>::value == true;
```

I'd say it's probably impossible but I am not an expert in C++.

Presumably, this tool can be used in a template function as

```
using allowed = int*;
using not_allowed = int*;

template <class T>
void f(T var) {
   static_assert(tool<T, allowed>::value &&
                 tool<T, not_allowed>::value == false, "");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Boost has a strong typedef see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp   _"...strong typedef
// guarentees that two types are distinguised even though the
// share the same underlying implementation...."_

Comment: `enum class int1_t : int {}; enum class int2_t : int {}; using t1 = int1_t*; using t2 = int2_t*;` ...and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @Eljay until you want to do `++*t1`, which becomes `++reinterpret_cast<int&>(*t1)`, which is rather verbose.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili • Aye, with great type safety comes great verbosity.

Answer (score 8):

No, there isn't. `t1` and `t2` are literally the same type. `using` does not introduce any new types. It simply gives an alias name to an already existing type.

If you want a distinct, but otherwise identical, "copy" of a type, you need to create a new class and implement the interface of the original type in the new class. (Inheritance may help, but not when the "copied" type is a non-class type like here. In the case of lambdas, you could simply repeat the lambda a second time to achieve this.)

There is currently no way to create a distinct "copy" of an arbitrary type, i.e. a *strong typedef*. The new type must be implemented explicitly. (Searching for *strong typedef* should give you some examples and libraries helping to implement it.)

Comment: Don't lambdas create distinct types?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow yes they do they create a unknown but uniquely named `struct`  _"...unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes. I would count defining a lambda implicitly as defining a class. I am not sure what part of the answer you were referencing, but I made some points clearer, I hope.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the concept of strong typedef in the context of struct and class, but I didn't know if it was possible for the basic types.

Comment: @oukore You can only add class and enumeration types (and implicitly compound types constructed from these), so the best you can do is implement a class which behaves (mostly) as if it was a `int*`. But such a type will work as replacement for `int*` often only if explicitly supported (e.g. in the iterator interface or the "fancy" pointer interface for allocators). `std::is_pointer`, trying to `reinterpret_cast`, etc, will all fail with such a replacement. A class replacement for `int` itself would be somewhat easier and there are probably many implementations of this around.

Answer (score 1):

You often want something like this so you can differentiate semantically different values that happen to have the same type. A way of doing that in C++ would be to have a thin layer of struct-wrapping around them.

```
struct Litre {
    int value;
};

struct Metre {
    int value;
};

// Maybe also define operators that make sense

void foo(Metre* pm) {
    // won't work with Litre*
}
```